Flask Session not storing data correctly
Here's my front-end that's sending the data:
async function notifyBackendAboutUpload(fileName) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/notify-upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ fileName }),
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();
        console.log(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error notifying the backend:', error);
    }

Here's my __init__.py:
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os


def create_app():
    load_dotenv()  # Load environment variables
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Configuration from environment variables
    app.config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    app.config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    app.config["AWS_REGION"] = os.getenv("AWS_REGION")
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE"] = "None"
    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

    from app.routes.routes import routes as routes_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(routes_blueprint)

    # Potentially add more blueprint registrations here

    return app

Here's my routes.py:
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
from app.services.aws_service import fetch_csv_from_s3

routes = Blueprint("routes", __name__)

CORS(routes, supports_credentials=True)

@routes.route("/test-s3-fetch")
def test_s3_fetch():
    bucket_name = "instanalytics"
    object_key = session.get("fileName")
    print('Retrieved from session:', object_key)
    if not object_key:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file name provided'}), 400
    # df = fetch_csv_from_s3(bucket_name, object_key)
    return jsonify({"message": f"FileName from session: {object_key}"})
    # return jsonify(df.head().to_dict())


@routes.route('/notify-upload', methods=['POST'])
def notify_upload():
    data=request.get_json()
    fileName=data['fileName']
    if not fileName:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Filename is required'}), 400

    session['fileName'] = fileName
    print('Stored in session:', session.get('fileName'))

    return redirect(url_for("routes.test_s3_fetch"))


@routes.route("/test-session")
def test_session():
    # Directly manipulate and check session data
    session["test"] = "Session is working!"
    print("Session data:", session)
    return jsonify({"testSessionValue": session.get("test")})

Now, I'm trying to use the sent file name from the front-end to use here and it's storing the fileName fine but it's not retrieving it correctly for some reason. Here's the logs:
Stored in session: aggregate.csv
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2024 05:47:18] "POST /notify-upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Retrieved from session: None
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2024 05:47:18] "GET /test-s3-fetch HTTP/1.1" 400 -

I'm new to flask so please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

looks to be how you are setting 'object_key', maybe read up on flask's docs for using the 'session' function
